# How to order rows in a repeating sequence?

Tags: mysql, sorting, unique, sequence

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  1 | Apple  | Message 1          |
|  2 | Orange | Message two        |
|  3 | Lime   | Some data          |
|  4 | Banana | More data          |
|  5 | Lime   | Boom. This is data |
|  6 | Pear   | I'm on 6 row       |
|  7 | Orange | Foo and Bar here   |
|  8 | Banana | Remember Baz       |
|  9 | Apple  | Big fat juicy data |
| 10 | Lime   | More values here   |
| 11 | Pear   | I'm almost empty   |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

And I have some sequence, like:

```
(Banana, Apple, Orange, Lime, Pear)
```

So I need to sort it like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  4 | Banana | More data          |
|  1 | Apple  | Message 1          |
|  2 | Orange | Message two        |
|  3 | Lime   | Some data          |
|  6 | Pear   | I'm on 6 row       |
|  8 | Banana | Remember Baz       |
|  9 | Apple  | Big fat juicy data |
|  7 | Orange | Foo and Bar here   |
|  5 | Lime   | Boom. This is data |
| 11 | Pear   | I'm almost empty   |
| 10 | Lime   | More values here   |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

How can I sort it like that and also have a pagination?

---

Or, generally, I need to sort rows so every N rows in the results set will be unique.

How to?

Comment: what is the logic of that sort? I would guess because `banana` is first on secuence should be 1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I want to list all table rows in PHP by pages through some time. And I want unique set of fruits every single pass. Note that IDs of fruits is different every time, and in real world I have some other columns in my table with some data in it.

Comment: Again explain what is the logic.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Imagine some table with unique data in it that has a column 'Fruit' with some repeating values. I want to request the table's rows by pages (say 10 results on a page) with unique 'Fruit' column values on every page.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've edited tables to clarify it.

Comment: Sorry but your description is ambiguous. You say want 10 result for page. Which 10?  You need to explain the logic.     Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The logic is to sort every N rows to exactly repeat the sequence.

Comment: That isnt enough logic why banana is 4??. I think you need a [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Banana is 4 because it is first row that was found for the first element of the sequence. I don't know how to do it more clever, but the key is - sort every N rows (5 in this example) to match the sequence, or, more general - sort all results to have UNIQUE fruits in every 5 rows

Comment: I think I see it now. ... You need create one aditional field to indicate the sort.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

First I use variable to see what is the first aparition of each fruit. That way I can show the first apparition of each fruit together `(rn = 1)`

Then use a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` to sort following your sequence.

The problem I see is `LIME = 3` is alone.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/BRHPTG5166)**

```
SELECT `ID`, `Fruit`, `Msg`, rn
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           @rn := IF(@fruit = `Fruit`,
                     @rn + 1,
                     if(@fruit := `Fruit`, 1, 1) 
                    ) as rn
    FROM Table1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @fruit := '') as var
    ORDER BY `Fruit`, `ID`
    ) T
ORDER BY rn, CASE `Fruit`  
                  WHEN 'Banana' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'Apple'  THEN 2
                  WHEN 'Orange' THEN 3
                  WHEN 'Lime'   THEN 4
                  WHEN 'Pear'   THEN 5
             END
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Tips:

- `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @fruit := '') as var` Here you create and initialize the variables `@rn` and `@fruit`.
- `ORDER BY Fruit, ID` Now I order by fruits so the same fruit are together. also order by `ID` so the smaller id appear first.
- `@rn :=` now you calculate the `rn` for each row.
- `IF(@fruit = Fruit,
      @rn + 1,
      if(@fruit := Fruit, 1, 1) 
      )`

  - You need to increase the @rn if you have the same fruit. like first apple, second apple,etc
  - if you get a new `fruit` @fruit will chage because I use `:=` and reset `@rn` counter to 1.
  - The first time you compare `@fruit = Fruit` you go for the second part of the IF because is initialized as `''`

Comment: Excellent! It does exactly what I needed! Many thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza !

Comment: What part you dont understand?

Comment: All that is inside T table

Comment: I add some explanation, hope help.

Comment: I'm not criticizing but I'd have broken `@rn := IF(@fruit = Fruit, @rn + 1, if(@fruit := Fruit, 1, 1)) as rn` into `@rn := IF(@fruit = Fruit, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @Fruit := Fruit AS currentFruit`. It is easier to read and less at risk of side effects from slight modifications.

Comment: @Uueerdo I used to did that way, but isn't safe. You can have weird result.  Read the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). The important quote is `"However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."`. This way the order of evaluation is guaranted.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza order of evaluation of select expressions is left to right; the order in function call arguments and if(,,) is less clear. In situations similar to this case, it is possible that `@fruit := Fruit` ends up evaluated before the check against `@fruit = Fruit`...or that the assignment still occurs after the check is evaluated as true (in this particular case that wouldn't actually be a problem, but in similar ones it could cause issues).

Comment: @Uueerdo Again check the manual. Clearly say the order of evaluation is undefined.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yeah, the docs for user variables specifically single out select expressions. However, in my experience, select expressions alone never cause this issue; problems usually seem to arise when the values are changed in the same expressions they are checked, or when attempts are made to "span" clauses (like using the same variable in SELECT and WHERE). _Of course, this undefined/inconsistent behavior is why so many people frown on using session variables in the first place._

Comment: @Uueerdo Well I learn that is the safe way of doing it and I see no need to go rogue.